# How should I imagine the cup product on a topological space/manifold/variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a "space" with a vector bundle $E$. Let $n$ be the dimension of $X$. Then there is a map $$H^1(X,E)\otimes \ldots\otimes H^1(X,E)\to H^n(X,\Lambda^n E).$$ This map is given by taken the cup-product.

Note. We take the tensor product $n$-times.

Question. How should I think about this map?

Note. By space I mean: topological space, manifold, analytic variety, algebraic variety, etc.

The cohomology I use should be a "useful" cohomology.

Is there any fundamental group hidden in this map?

Comment: Isn't it just the exterior product?  That is, $[\omega_1]\otimes\cdots\otimes[\omega_n]$ maps to $[\omega_1\land \cdots \land \omega_n]$.